# question deleted - reputation is gone, but the tag rating is still there

Tags: discussion

recently i answered on a question, with maybe not the best answer there is, but it was accepted as the answer to the question.
consequently i received my reputation, but someone voted my answer down.
now the question was deleted and my rep is gone, but the bad tag rating is still there.
i really dont find this approach to be consequent.
either delete both rep and tag rating or keep both. or is there a good explenation why this seperation makes sense ?

Comment: i also dont understand where i got the 14 rep here on meta

Comment: reputation on meta is derived from reputation on the main site and is updated periodically, this means a few hours after reputation changes have been applied on the main site, the reputation changes will reflect on meta.

Comment: thats quiet strange then as well, because on stackoverflow i have 54 rep and on the corresponding meta i have just 1

Comment: It's different for meta.stackoverflow.com - this is the only meta site that calculates its own reputation as it acts as a central site for discussions regarding the Stack Exchange system

Comment: having rep in meta really does not matter, so what is the problem?

Comment: there is basically no problem, but it is kind of strange. and i thought such strange behavior is to discuss in meta

Answer (score -1, accepted):

my reputation only disappeared after i got new rep on the main site (the non-meta one)

Answer (score 3):

Tag ratings update overnight, rather than instantly, so any changes to them should be correctly reflected tomorrow. Reputation changes are done in real time, so the deletion of the question would immediately revoke the reputation granted from answering it.

Comment: something is wrong here. as you can see my rep is still there in meta, but lost in the nonmeta... so ?

Comment: @user2664856 Things in meta take time to refresh.

Comment: yes, but more than a week ?